# Which of the following quotient rings $F[x]/(x^2+1)$ is not a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

(A) $F=\mathbb{R}$

(B) $F=\mathbb{Q}$

(C) $F=\Bbb Z_2$

(D) $F=\Bbb Z_3$

I know that polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. I have only confusion about $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: on $\Bbb Z_2$ you have $1=-1$, thus $x^2+1=x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, then the polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb Z_2$.